# venue seats design in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am web developer and working on a event reservation system

I am looking for script to design venue seats in any javascripts libraries plugin

an example for what I want to do with that plugin

[image: an example for what I want to do with that plugin]

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Diagram for JavaScript](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejdiagram) supports creating any kind of diagram including seat design.

[Example](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/b1ofxdtv)

[image: Diagram JS seating map]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

What about [this](http://www.topjqueryplugins.com/2016/04/jquery-seat-charts-to-display-seat-map.html)?

> JSC is a jquery seat map plugin. This plugin help to design the seat
>   arrangement of any layout, like bus, conference hall etc. This plugin
>   help on designing the seat map for booking a ticket.

[image]

Obviously, you would have to customeize it.